# Executing PHP via command line

Tags: php, command-line

I want to be able to **execute PHP via command line with a $_GET variable**.  I understand I can do this with `exec`, but I'd like to understand more of the security risk and what things I should look out for.  The parameter I want to pass is a **MySQL auto_incremented ID** returned from MySQL, so I'm not concerned with user input.  But by merely allowing this to happen what things should be considered in regards to security?

The script will accept an order ID and send the customer an email invoice.  This allows me to perform this function from multiple sections of the site only maintaining the code in 1 location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you really need to execute this from command line. Create a PHP function and include it in your multiple sections instead: it will be faster. Per example:

```
function sendInvoice($orderId) {
    // do something
}
```

Then call it:

```
include_once('send_invoice.inc.php');
sendInvoice(42);
```

This still allows code reuse and a single place where to maintain the code.

Comment: +1 much better solution then using a shell script for this kind of task

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use argv/argc?

```
$id = isset($argv[1]) ? (int)$argv[1] : (int)$_REQUEST['id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

For cmdline scripts `$argv` is the answer. But you can indeed inject `$_GET` variables as well. Just pre-define the `QUERY_STRING` environment variable accordingly:

```
putenv("QUERY_STRING=id=$id");
exec("php script.php");
```

Regarding security, cmdline php scripts could be more worriesome on shared hosting servers if they initiate administrative actions. But there is not much you can do about that. Keep strictly cmdline scripts out of the document_root, and apply file or directory permission if anyhow possible.